# How do you link to books on the Kindle from a Kindle app?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

I am wondering, is there a way to link to kindle books from kindle apps to make it easy for users to get the books?

And also, by the same virtue, is there a way to link to kindle apps from kindle apps to make it simplest for the users to download the app?

Is there a special url I should use?

For example, this is one of my apps:
[http://www.amazon.com/Problemio-com-Funding-Fundraising-Ideas/dp/B00AKRD1NQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AKRD1NQ)

How do I correctly link to it from another Kindle app?

I can do something like this but I am sure there is a better way, right?

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b);          
b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
{  
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {           
      Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
              Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.com/Problemio-com-Funding-Fundraising-Ideas/dp/B00AKRD1NQ"));

      startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for Deep Linking into the store for a specific app you should follow the [linking to the Amazon AppStore](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/in-app-purchasing/docs/deeplink) format. As well as linking to apps it also appears to correctly link to books if you use the ASIN (eg http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?asin=B000UVBSYQ)